# About manifolds after attaching handles.

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

I'm reading R.E. Gompf and A.I. Stipsicz, 4-Manifolds and Kirby Calculus. I don't understand Remarks 4.4.1 on page 116-117 [Google books here](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=ahLKzRUTBbUC&pg=PA116&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false).

At first I can't understand why we take immersed disk $D \subset Y$ with boundary $K \subset \partial _{+}Y$.

Next, I can't understand on the counterexamples

### $X \approx D^4 , X ' \approx S^2\times D^2-intD^4$ .

If you can help me, then please teach me the reason for this